# Xcode GIT push to remote by default?

Tags: xcode

Does anybody know how to have the 'Push to remote:' checkbox ticked by default?[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to do this yet?

Comment: I'm interested too. I'm assuming it's a no if no-one has mentioned it but if someone with more experience would comment for closure that'd be great!